# It looks like you sent an email to a Trello card, but the text was too large to fit in one comment

Tags: trello, gmail-filters

I have configured my Gmail account to redirect every new email message to one of my Trello boards. The configuration works fine and I get every email created as a Trello card, which is what I want.

My problem is that most of the times I receive a notification from Trello telling me this message:

> It looks like you sent an email to a Trello card, but the text was too large to fit in one comment.

[image]

They say the text was too large and it was cut off. I don't have a problem with that, as I understand Trello's limits about emails.

The real problem is that this notification is really annoying. Most of my inbox looks like this:
[image]

With every single message coming between the *important* emails there's a Trello notification.

Is there any way to stop this? I tried to create a Gmail filter to immediately delete this kind of notifications from Trello but I'm afraid it will delete the whole conversation and not only the single message.

Comment: Rather than filtering to delete, filter to a special label just for these and "Skip the Inbox". Then you can review and delete at your leisure, while retaining any important messages that might get trapped by your filter.